# DrJava switch(String) issue

Tags: java, drjava

DrJava is having problem compiling a very very simple switch statement.

This is a simple example:

```
switch (sc.next()) {
  case "abc": output = 0; break;
  case "bcd": output = 1; break;
}
```

DrJava returns the following message on the first line.

**Error: Cannot switch on a value of type java.lang.String. Only convertible int values or enum constants are permitted**

SSH Secure Shell has no problem compiling it, and I heard switch(String) is implemented since long time ago. What can I do to fix this issue on DrJava?

*My DrJava is of the newest version.

Comment: switch(String) can be used for java7 and higher version.check your java version if its less than java7 then you can not use switch(Strings)

Comment: I have no idea what DrJava is, but switch on Strings is supported since Java 7. If you use a Java 6 or even older JDK, that won't compile.

Comment: I strongly suspect that DrJava is basically not aware of Java 7 features. Is there any reason you *need* to use this rather than (say) Eclipse or Netbeans?

Comment: Thank you guys for your help. I installed JDK8 and now it works fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your Java version? Switch statements on strings only started in Java 7.

Else you will have to use the good old if condition :

```
String text = sc.next()

if(text.equals("abc")) {
    output = 0;
} else if (text.equals("bcd")) {
    output = 1;
}
```

Comment: I have Version 7 Update 51 according to http://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp

Comment: Have you tried setting your classpath correctly then?

Comment: Check this link out for it : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html

Comment: Just installed JDK8 and it works fine now! Thank you so much haha

Answer (score 0):

You can only do so in Java7, as shown [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/new-java-7-feature-string), your other alternative is to use `if` statements. If you want to see what Java version you are running, typing `java -v` or `java --version` in your console should give you what version you have.

Answer (score 0):

In JDK 7 we can use String comparison in switch. In early java version like (6,4,..). We cannot use String in switch statement.